# Child div affects parent div in css and triggers jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have parent div with class a "very-big-div" that nests another "container-div" that by its turn also nests another child divs. The very big div's made to act like a button and the div that come right after it is a container that appears when I click the very big div.

```
<div class="very-big">
  <div class="container">
   <!-- Some other more nested divs that has anchors and buttons  -->
   <div class="friend-request">
     <div class="button-div">
     <button class="accept">Trigger</button>
      <button class="refuse">Trigger</button>
     </div>
     </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is 2 things first:   **the css problem has not yet been solved**

I assigned a hover pseudo class for the "very-big-div", and whenever I hover the "container-div" the hover properties(background-color) is applied to the "very-big-div". This is not what I intend to make, I want to only hover "very-big" div for the hover to apply.

```
.very-big{
 background-color:green;
  }
```

The second problem is : I have a jquery that deals with the container so it is toggled on/off by the "very-big-div"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#container-div").hide(); 
$("#very-big-div").click(function(){
$("#container-div").toggle();
 });
 });
```

the container has both anchor and button tags whenever I click the an anchor or a button inside the container it is toggled to close itself, and that is not what I want, what I want is just when I only press the "very-big-div" the toggle is activated.

Comment: Just a tip: It would be way easier to answer your question if it had the markup structure as well.

Comment: Events propagate up, so if you want an event to only apply to a child-level container you need to remember to call `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Jhecht will you demonstrate in relation to my jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as @Jhecht has given the answer, I have just inherited his to mine.

You can stop propagation of the click of child element that trigger toggle by using `target` and excluding all the child elements of your `.very-big` container as:

```
$(".very-big").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is('.very-big *')) {
      $(".container").toggle();
    }
});
```

### Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hide();
  $(".very-big").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is('.very-big *')) {
      $(".container").toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="very-big">
  Other Text
  <div class="container">
    This is text to fill stuff out so I can click on it.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but another problem presents itself is that I have a button inside the container, now when I click that button it just triggers the event all over again ( the container flicks and re appears again )as if I clicked the big div. how to stop that

Comment: @AndrewMk i.e. why we at **SO** request users to post your full code or at least minimal code to reproduce the issue. I request to edit/update your question again.

Comment: Ok completely understood

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but I am not sure if it is what you need.

Please add in the minimum HTML, CSS, and Javascript needed to *fully* recreate the error you are seeing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hide();
  $(".very-big").click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var current = $(e.toElement);
    if (current.is('.container')) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
    $('.container').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="very-big">
  Other Text
  <div class="container">
    This is text to fill stuff out so I can click on it.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This presents my problem. Try to press the "This is text to fill stuff out so I can click on it.", and it will toggle the hide as if you pressed "other text ". I want to prevent that. I want to prevent the propagation from the parent to the child, so the parent is the only one will be affected by the event or the method